# Why does my react app go to the custom 404 not found page when the link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router, package.json

My app was built using create-react-app. It all works fine once I'm using the app except when I click on the link from my portfolio website (on MAMP local host), it loads the custom 404 page instead of the Home component. When I load the app from npm run start it lands on the Home component first, I want it to do this on localhost and my live website too.

I've tried changing the "homepage" in package.json to "." but it still does the same thing.

```
 // App.js

 import React from 'react';
 import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
 import Header from './components/layout/Header';
 import NotFound from './components/layout/NotFound';
 import Alert from './components/layout/Alert';
 import Home from './components/content/Home';
 import Movie from './components/content/movies/Movie';
 import AlertState from './context/alert/AlertState';
 import MovieState from './context/movies/MovieState';

 const App = () => {
     return (
         <MovieState>`enter code here`
             <AlertState>
                 <Router>
                     <Header text={"Movie App"}/>
                     <Alert />
                     <Switch>
                         <Route path='/' component={Home} />
                         <Route path='/movie/:title' component={Movie} />
                         <Route component={NotFound} />
                     </Switch>
                 </Router>
             </AlertState>
         </MovieState>
     );
 }

 export default App
```

package.json

```
    {
      "name": "film_app",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "homepage": ".",
      "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19.0",
        "react": "^16.9.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
        "react-scripts": "3.1.1"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
      },
      "browserslist": {
        "production": [
          ">0.2%",
          "not dead",
          "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
          "last 1 chrome version",
          "last 1 firefox version",
          "last 1 safari version"
        ]
      }
    }
```

```
    // Home.js
    import React from 'react';
    import Search from './Search';
    import Movies from './movies/Movies';

    const Home = () => {
        return (
            <>
                <Search />
                <Movies />
            </>
        )
    }

    export default Home
```

```
    // NotFound.js
    import React from 'react';

    const NotFound = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>
                    Page Not Found
                    <p className='lead' style={notFoundStyles}>
                        The page you are looking for does not exist
                    </p>
                </h1>
            </div>
        )
    }

    const notFoundStyles = {
        textAlign: 'center',
    };

    export default NotFound
```

There is no error message, it just shows the NotFound component rather than the Home component.

Comment: Try this for the NotFound Component
 <Route path="*" component={DefaultRoute} />

Comment: Won't I just get the "component not found" error then because I have no component called DefaultRoute?

Comment: Add this as the last route <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />

Comment: Please include the code for the link you are clicking on your portfolio website. I suspect that you perhaps have the deployed version of this React application hosted underneath a folder path so it doesn't start at `/`.

Comment: as mentioned please share you Link code. Just FYI updating the homepage in the package.json won't change anything - homepage refers to this: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#homepage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `exact` flag to your `Home` route, and `path='/'` to the fallback route.

```
<Switch>
    <Route path='/' exact={true} component={Home} />
    <Route path='/movie/:title' component={Movie} />
    <Route path='/' component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: that workerd for me, brilliant!